# Bibliography string 'and' untranslated error BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, biber

My bibliography is not working correctly. I get a bunch of errors in overleaf:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'and' untranslated at entry 'Grigorescu2020WebWild' on input line 47.
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'in' untranslated at entry 'Grigorescu2020WebWild' on input line 47.
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'volume' untranslated at entry 'Grigorescu2020WebWild' on input line 47.
```

I use this code:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
hyperref=true,
natbib=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=three,
sortcites=false,
maxbibnames=50,
maxcitenames=3,
giveninits=true,
isbn=true,
url=true,
doi=true
]
{biblatex}
```

I imported all papers, articles and books via [mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/search/).
Example of a entry inside .bib file:

```
@inproceedings{Grigorescu2020WebWild,
    title = {{Web application honeypot published in the wild}},
    year = {2020},
    booktitle = {Proceedings - RoEduNet IEEE International Conference},
    author = {Grigorescu, Octavian and Sandescu, Cristian and Caba, Alexandru},
    volume = {2020-December},
    doi = {10.1109/RoEduNet51892.2020.9324870},
    issn = {20681038}
}
```

As you can see these keywords, that are not recognized are rendered in bold text.

[image]

Where is the issue, all I can find is, that 'and' is the right keyword to separate authors and still biblatex has a problem with it.

Comment: None of these messages are errors, they are warnings. You either write your document in a language that is not supported by `biblatex` or you load `babel` or `polyglossia` and fail to pass a language to it. We can only help you, if you show us a fully compilable example document that reproduces the issue.

Comment: The document and the entries in the bib file are in English.

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,paper=A4,DIV=15,BCOR=12mm,abstract=true,headsepline,headings=normal]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

Are there specific parts that are interesting? I could post the full main file and the configuration file on Pastebin if it helps

Comment: Here is the pastebin to main and config file: https://pastebin.com/SNQPkSVD
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document appears to load `babel` with

```
\usepackage{babel}
```

but you never actually set a document language.

---

Either pass the document language along to your document class as in

```
 \documentclass[12pt,oneside,paper=A4,DIV=15,BCOR=12mm,abstract=true,headsepline,headings=normal, english]{scrreprt}
```

or pass it to `babel`

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

This assumes your document is in English.